# How to get the values from the RecyclerView using Espresso

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-espresso

I want to get the all values from the RecyclerView using Espresso. I am able to get only the visible values from the recyclerView. But not able to get the values which are visible when scrolling.
Ex. In RecyclerView 25 items are there and Only 7 items are visible. Others are visible when we scroll it. I am able to get the values of 7 items. But want to get all the values
Can Anyone please tell me how to get this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show the code of your espresso test ?

Comment: val noOfItem = getCountFromRecyclerView(R.id.RecyclerView)
        for (i in 0 until noOfItem) {
            val RowValues=getText(onView(getElementFromMatchAtPosition(withId(R.id.rowNumber), i))) }       where getCountFromRecyclerView method is to get the count from recyclerView and Its returning 25

Comment: Hi Team...Any updates on the above question

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember how `RecyclerView` really works. It optimizes showing scrollable elements, by displaying only items that are currently within the visible range.

In other words: *before you scroll to items below, they are no `Views` within the `RecyclerView` to represent those items. Just the data in the `Adapter`.*

So the way you should be probably doing your test is to:

1. Verify proper state of currently visible items.
2. Scroll the `RecyclerView` (using one of the [`RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions) methods)
3. Verify proper state of currently visible items.
4. Scroll the `RecyclerView`.
5. ...